# How to get <apex:inputtext> value in javavscript?

Tags: visualforce, javascript

"textvalue" is a string {get;set in my controller. Onclick of button i want to get the value of "textvalue" in my script to do some validation.

```
vf:
<apex:inputText value="{!textvalue}" styleClass="slds-select" style="width : 57%;"/> 
<input id="recordHidden" type="hidden" name="theHiddenInput" value="{!textvalue}"/>
<Button  onclick="check();return false;">Enter This Reject Reason</Button>



function check(){
 alert(document.getElementById('recordHidden').value);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<apex:inputText value="{!textvalue}" styleClass="slds-select" style="width : 57%;" id="textId"/> 
var CaseSub= $('[id$=textId]').val();
alert(CaseSub);
```

By setting an id to input text you can get the value in script like above

Comment: It's fine (encouraged, even) to answer your own question, but I'd like to see more substance to your answer here. Explaining how this selector works, how it solved your question, and any changes that you might have needed to make to your markup (I don't see an Id value specified that would cause your selector to find anything) would help other people with similar questions figure out how to get themselves un-stuck.

Comment: Thanks @DerekF .I have edited my answer properly .